# woocommerce set_stock_quantity not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a plugin that will update the stock quantity of woocommerce it's some sort of third party cart I want to sync the quantity of woocommerce from other website data. my code is

```
$quantity = floatval(5);
$product_id = 10;
$woocmmerce_instance = new WC_Product( $product_id );
$woocmmerce_instance->set_stock_quantity($quantity);
```

but this throws an error PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method WC_Product::set_stock_quantity()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used [wc_update_product_stock()](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_update_product_stock/) for Update a product's stock amount.

put this code in your plugin where you perform operation for update product quantity.

```
global $woocommerce;
$quantity = 5;
$product_id = 10;
$woocmmerce_instance = new WC_Product( $product_id );
$new_quantity=wc_update_product_stock( $woocmmerce_instance, $quantity);
```

Comment: how can i enable "Manage stock" ?

Answer (score 10):

You need to call save() on the WC_Product instance to effect your changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is you need to add the "wc_update_product_stock" function, Put this code in your plugin where you perform operation for update product quantity.

```
global $woocommerce;
$quantity = 5;
$product_id = 10;
$woocmmerce_instance = new WC_Product( $product_id );
$new_quantity=wc_update_product_stock( $woocmmerce_instance, $quantity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `new WC_Product($product_id)`

Instead you should use:

```
    global $woocommerce;
    $quantity = 5;
    $product_id = 10;
    $woocmmerce_instance = wc_get_product( $product_id );
if(isset($woocmmerce_instance) && $woocmmerce_instance !== null && $woocmmerce_instance !== false){
    $new_quantity=wc_update_product_stock( $woocmmerce_instance, $quantity);
}
```

Or that way:

```
    $quantity = 5;
    $product_id = 10;
    $woocmmerce_instance = wc_get_product( $product_id );
if(isset($woocmmerce_instance) && $woocmmerce_instance !== null && $woocmmerce_instance !== false){
$woocmmerce_instance->set_stock_quantity( $woocmmerce_instance, $quantity);
$woocmmerce_instance->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solve it saving the product after set the price.

```
$product =   wc_get_product( $product_id );
$product->set_stock_quantity( $some_stock );

$product->save();
wc_delete_product_transients( $id );
```